Serverless Sagemaker inference endpoint failed
I am trying to deploy a SageMaker model using a serverless endpoint. The model is stored in ECR, and I created the model and endpoint configuration successfully. However, when I try to deploy the serverless endpoint, I encounter the following error in CloudWatch:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'model.joblib.af1a34Bf'
The .joblib file referenced in the error does not exist; the model actually uses a different .joblib file stored in S3, which has full access permissions.
Here’s what I’ve checked so far:

IAM role associated with the endpoint has s3:GetObject, s3:ListBucket, and s3:GetObjectVersion permissions.
The S3 path is correct, and I verified that the file exists in the bucket.
The S3 bucket policy allows access to the IAM role.
The endpoint works fine in a provisioned mode; the issue occurs only in serverless mode.

Does anyone know why this error might be occurring or how to fix it? Any insights would be appreciated!
